# #id h1, h2, h3 { } being overwritten by a previous #id h1, h2, h3 { }

Tags: html, css

I have this .css to control the h1 h2 and h3s inside of different divs.

```
  #about h1, h2, h3{
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #797979;
}


#consult h3{
  color: #797979;
  margin-top: 59px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
}
```

I have two different divs one #consult and another #about.

However, the #consult h3 is inheriting everything from the #about h3?

Comment: please provide the corresponding HTML so we can check if the CSS selectors are actually valid for your page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this because your existing rules `h3` include every single h3 in the form. By putting `#about h3`, the rules will only be apply to `h3` in `#about` scope which will prevent `h3` to override your `#consult h3`.

```
#about h1, #about  h2,  #about h3{
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this if you added at least a little bit of explanation as to why the selectors are wrong (I already know, but the answer should be useful to others who are likely making a similar mistake).

Comment: I don't think this can be confirmed as the answer to OP's question because there is no HTML provided, and we can't just assume he uses h3's inside (grand-)parents w/ id about or consult... for now

Comment: @Azder I think there's enough contextual clues in the question to make this a valid answer, though you are correct in that there is a certain amount of assumption necessary. The last line in the question, specifically, indicates an incomplete understanding of how the selectors were being applied.

Comment: it is not just the "contextual clues" it may simply not work because his HTML is the part where there is a bug i.e. he also meant to do what we guess, but didn't ;)

Answer (score 5):

Commas in your selector strings (`#about h1, h2, h3`) break the selector totally. For example, you first CSS rule;

```
#about h1, h2, h3{
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
```

is the same as this;

```
#about h1 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
```

That you really want is this;

```
#about h1, #about h2, #about h3{
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
```

Which is equivalent to this;

```
#about h1 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
#about h2 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
#about h3 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #797979;
}
```